# Creating pivot table in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to try and create a pivot table in Excel, but it doesn't appear to be working

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Dim AllData As Range
Set AllData = selection.CurrentRegion

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=AllData).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'[Process Data v2.xls]Pivot'!R4C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

The error is with the pivot table section, and its a runtime error 5. Invalid procedure call or argument.

I have tried recording a macro and having a precise range in the script and it works, but replacing this with the 'Alldata' variable breaks it. I tried a lot of things but can't figure out why its not working

Comment: Try just using `Set AllData = [A1].CurrentRegion` , Remember that if any cells that are touching your data have data they will be included in Currentregion.

Comment: Better would be to just use your Table Or List Directly.

Comment: Now it's stopped working again. I didn't change any code, all I did was exit the workbook and open it again!

Comment: Did you save the code once it was working?

Comment: Are you adding a pivot table with the same name as an existing one?

Comment: I saved the code and its still the same, but now it doesn't work. The code deletes existing pivot tables further up but they will have had the same name

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting up your code so that the pivot cache and table creation are separated: thet will give you a better idea of where the actual error lies:

```
Dim pc, pt
Dim AllData As Range

Set AllData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                        SourceData:=AllData)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
              "'[Process Data v2.xls]Pivot'!R4C1", _
              TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Comment: It doesn't like that code, wont even let me run the vba with it. I think the problem is with the AllData part because the code worked when I recorded it, just when I replaced the hardcoded selection with Alldata